# aggregate bins in large GRanges efficiently

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, genomicranges

I have a SummarizedExperiment (but we can consider it a GRanges).
What I want is to reduce the number of intervals, keeping only one row for every identical adjacent `mcol(gr)`, important is to also keep track of the new extend interval.

Thanks a lot!

```
gr <- GRanges(
seqnames = Rle(c("chr1"), c(12)),
ranges = IRanges(1:12*10, end = 1:12*10+5),
state1 = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,1),
state2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,5,5,6,6,1,1))
```

The resulting GRanges should look like this:

```
gr2 <- GRanges(
  seqnames = Rle(c("chr1"), c(8)),
  ranges = IRanges(start = c(10,40,50,60,70,80,90,110),
  end =  c(35,45,55,65,75,85,105,125)),
  state1 = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1), state2 = c(1,2,2,2,5,5,6,1))​
```

Edit: I have edit the Granges so that a state pair is present also in non adjacent intervals (this second 1,1 pair has to be report independely from the first)
Sorry my initial solution was also wrong!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an artificial factor, make sure the levels are in the order of occurrence in the factor (rather than the default alphabetical) to avoid re-arranging the GRanges, and split the `GRanges` object

```
f0 = paste(gr$state1, gr$state2, sep=".")
f = factor(f0, levels=unique(f0))
grl = split(gr, f)
```

Get the ranges and relevant metadata

```
grf = unlist(range(grl), use.names=FALSE)
mcols(grf) = mcols(gr)[!duplicated(f),]
```

`split()`, `range()`, and `unlist()` should all be 'fast' for data of this size.

To also split on chromosome, add that to the factor

```
f0 = paste(seqnames(gr), gr$state1, gr$state2, sep=".")
```

To split in some other way, e.g., only when states are adjacent, figure out a way to make the appropriate factor, e.g.,

```
f0 = paste(
    seqnames(gr),
    cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(gr$state1) != 0)),
    cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(gr$state2) != 0)),
    sep=".")
```

Ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Comment: HI Martin, Thanks for you help, your solution is really good, but does not work if a particular state pair is also in two different genome regions (lets say chr1 and than chr21). This is a same dataset as an example (I also have more than two state) GRanges(
  seqnames = Rle(c("chr1"), c(12)),
  ranges = IRanges(1:12*10, end = 1:12*10+5),
  state1 = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,1),
  state2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,5,5,6,6,1,1))

Comment: @user3300849 I added two additional suggestions for constructing `f`; the idea is the same, though.

Comment: Sorry I m to dull .. was is diff(x) now? (an thanks for your help!!)

Comment: is this correct ? diff(matrix(c(gr1$state1, gr1$state2), ncol = 2))

Comment: @user3300849 I updated my response with a more complete answer to your updated question

Comment: I have to sort before adding mcols to avoid misalign (the grf is not sort after unlist)

Comment: @user3300849 not sort, but make sure the splitting vector is a factor with the levels organized so that the order of the split GRanges does not change compared to the original. I updated the answer with `f0` the original and `f` the correctly-ordered splitting vector.